# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) Setup - Unable to Read Credential File Despite Correct Path

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have been facing a persistent issue while trying to set up the Google Analytics Data API (GA4) using the quickstart guide provided by Google ([quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#php_1)).

The specific problem arises when I'm setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I have correctly placed the `credentials.json` file alongside the `quickstart.php` file and used PHP `putenv` function to set the variable as follows:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="'.__DIR__.'/credentials.json"');
```

Unfortunately, every time I run my test, I encounter this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught DomainException: Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file "/google/credentials.json" does not exist in /google/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php:81 Stack trace: #0 /google/vendor/google/auth/src/ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php(160): Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader::fromEnv() #1 /google/vendor/google/gax/src/CredentialsWrapper.php(267): Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getCredentials() #2 /google/vendor/google/gax/src/CredentialsWrapper.php(136): Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::buildApplicationDefaultCredentials() #3 /google/vendor/google/gax/src/GapicClientTrait in /google/vendor/google/gax/src/CredentialsWrapper.php on line 275
```

I triple-checked the file paths and everything seems in order, but the error persists.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue or does anyone have insights on how to resolve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Additional Info:

- Language: PHP
- API: Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Thank you in advance!

Full Code for Reference:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="'.__DIR__.'/credentials.json"');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'city',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: is the folder `google` at root level within your hierarchy or is it a sub-folder to the current script operating directory?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius the folder `google` isn't at the root level, it is within another couple of directories just outside the `vendor` folder, I removed the rest of the path since I deemed it unnecessary to include if it helps the actual path to the `credentials.json` is `/srv/www/DOMAIN/docs/marketingdream/inc/google/`

Comment: @TommyCunningham — Then it looks like the problem is a typo and you forgot the `.` at the beginning of the path (or have an extra `/` at the beginning of the path you shouldn't have).

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo full code is now included for reference

Comment: @Quentin - I already checked for all that, and the path is correct I am able to get the contents of the credentials file using `file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/credentials.json');` so I know that it is not the path the API just doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file "/google/credentials.json"` - the path portion of that variable/constant begins with `/` which suggests that `google` is at root level. If `google` is a sub-directory for the current operating script as you suggest then the path should either be a relative path or even a fully qualified path?!

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - As stated I removed the rest of the path from my question, I am providing it with the full absolute path to the credentials file using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/srv/www/DOMAIN/docs/marketingdream/inc/google/credentials.json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can guess the issue is that it cant find the file or your web server doesnt have access to the file where you have it placed.

You can force feed it and bypass the env var for testing or just bypass it completely

```
// Authenticate using a keyfile path
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'credentials' => $service_account_key_file_path
]);
```

Comment: I tried this using `$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(['credentials' => __DIR__.'/credentials.json']);` and now I am getting the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Google\Protobuf\Internal\bccomp() in /google/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:961`

Comment: The error `Call to undefined function Google\Protobuf\Internal\bccomp()` was because I didn't have the `bcmath` extension installed, once I'd installed it this bypass worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=" . __DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
```

NOT:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="'.__DIR__.'/credentials.json"');
```

it seems that the problem is in :

```
'.__DIR__.'
```